# How to pass class Type to a function to cast it in the function

Tags: c#, class, casting

At compile time, I don't know what exact type I will pass to a method, but I am sure that this type will contain some property. How can I pass a Type to a function to perform casting in the function? I would like to get something like that:

```
foo (classType cl)
{
    int x = ((cl)SomeClass).Id.Value;
}
```

Comment: What task are you trying to solve? You could make use of either interfaces, generics or other means. But solution depends on what are you trying to achieve in this situation.

Comment: I'm trying to get sth like this:
int id = ((cl)SomeClass).id.Value;

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? I don't think you can cast a class (in your example SomeClass) to another class. You can cast an object to another class. But you would have to know it is of a type that can be cast to another type (or you will get an InvalidCastException). You could use generics and a constraint on the type parameter, but then you wouldn't have to cast it. So I'm puzzled at what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is you're trying to solve.

Comment: What exactly is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I will make a wild guess that at compile time you don't know what exact type you will pass to a method, but you're sure that this type will contain some property, and you need to use it in that method?

Then you would want to make an interface with that property, and use it as a type of your method argument

Comment: @Trovgar - that is what i want to do. Thanks, I'll try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answer won't work when using .id because your T type isn't constrained. The class has no idea that any T could implement a field/property called id

Imagine you used  instead

```
foo <int>()
```

T would be int and int doesn't have an id field/property

You can constrain though

```
foo <T>()
  where T : ClassTypeThatImplementsId
{
  int x = ((T)SomeClass).Value;
}
```

Though this means that T can only be of that particular type. Is there a base class that has ID that you can use instead? I don't know if this is the solution you want though...

Edit:

In response to your post:

```
foo <T>()
  where T : BaseClass
{
  int x = ((T)SomeClass).Value;
}
```

Should work assuming BaseClass implements 'Value' (and assuming SomeClass comes from somewhere as there appears to be no reference to it in the method!)

Comment: The OP posted **foo (classType cl) { int x = ((cl)SomeClass).id.Value; }** in a comment, so I assumed id

Comment: Thank You.
There is actually the base class that has ID. But what I want to do is to get that ID from derived class. Can I do it like this:?
**foo <T>()
  where T : BaseClass
{
  int x = ((T)SomeClass).x.Value;
}**
T derives from BaseClass

Comment: Yes - just use where T : BaseClass - this will ensure you can use any type that derives from BaseClass including BaseClass itself and the property will be accessible from the templated cast

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work (if it is this you are trying to achieve), but you don't need casting:

```
public interface IHasInteger
{
    int Value { get; }
}

public class HasInteger : IHasInteger
{
    public int Value { get { return 1; } }
}

public class AlsoHasInteger : IHasInteger
{
    public int Value { get { return 2; } }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new HasInteger();
        var b = new AlsoHasInteger();
        var c = new object();
        Console.WriteLine(GetInteger(a));
        Console.WriteLine(GetInteger(b));
        Console.WriteLine(GetInteger(c));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int GetInteger(object o)
    {
        if (o is IHasInteger)
        {
            int x = ((IHasInteger)o).Value;
            return x;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interfaces sound like the way to go here since the OP seems to want a re-usable strongly typed property

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

```
foo <T>() : where SomeTypeHavingValue
{
  int x = ((T)SomeClass).Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it was actually meant to be: 
foo (classType cl)
{
    int x = ((cl)SomeClass).id.Value;
}
and now i get error like this:

Error 4 'tp' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'tp' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: try importing `System.Collections.Generics` namespace as `using System.Collections.Generics`

Comment: What the? How can this work? How does T have a .Value property? 3 upvotes? :S

Comment: @Peter It was assumed that the type will have a Value.

Comment: @Asif, Ah, ok, but my comment was from before you added the type constraint. Now the code could work, except that you would have to replace 'SomeClass' with an instance of an object. Now you're trying to cast a class to T.